# Removing duplicates(non-exact) tuples from a list in python

Tags: python, set, duplicates, tuples

Consider a list of tuples:
`[(14,1), (10,5), (8,7), (1,14)]`

I need to eliminate one of `(1,14)` & `(14,1)`. So the expected result should be `[(14,1),(10,5),(8,7)]` or `[(10,5),(8,7),(1,14)]`

**Note**: Order doesn't matter.

I'm aware that `set()` can be used to eliminate exact duplicates. Also combinations would not be of much help too because all of them add up to the same total.

Comment: Instead a list of tuples you could have a set of sets.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you please explain further instead of downvoting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the scenario, it would be wise to instead use a set of sets. Sets do not allow duplicates, and order was specified to not matter.

If you have no control of the creation of the data and instead must convert from your current data to this, you can this to convert your current data:

```
{frozenset(i) for i in dataset}
```

You have to use `frozenset` as `set` is not a hashable type. This is no more restrictive than using a `tuple`.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye This works for this case in giving what the OP exactly wanted, but will not always return what OP expected. Test for `[(14,1), (10,5), (8,7), (1,14), (12, 3)]` - the `(12,3)` will be swapped to `(3,12)`. Given the qualifications for the data, it should be sets all around anyways.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion!

Comment: sorry about that. I thought I could accept multiple answers.

Comment: @vinayhegde That's fine - there's a first time to learn everything. The award that can be given for all good answers is an upvote.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

sort the tuple

```
data = [(14,1), (10,5), (8,7), (1,14)]
set( [ tuple(sorted(i)) for i in data])
```

output:

```
set([(5, 10), (1, 14), (7, 8)])
```